# Download list of the name of every country in Western languages

Tags: data-request, geospatial, dictionary

I am looking for a list of all (say 220) countries in all Western languages. At the very least, all 24 official EU languages. so that's a 220x24 or so table. So it should look something like:

```
  EN        BG              CS              DA
Afghanistan Афганистан      Afghánistán     Afghanistan
Albania     Албания         Albánie         Albanien
Algeria     Алжир           Alžírsko        Algeriet
```

etc

Ideally as a CSV or tab-separated download.

I have looked at CLDR but its focus is on locales, I can not see a list of country names in multiple languages.

There are plenty of web pages with human-readable versions run together as text, not separated.

Comment: if you provide a link to the human-readable versions, we can see if they can be parsed/scraped to be machine readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of the names of each ISO country code in up to 114 languages was produced by Jonah Ellison in 2011 (the number of languages available varies by country).

There's a link to the UTF-8 CSV file on his page: [21,640 Translated Country Names](http://jonahellison.com/21640-translated-country-names-unicode-csv).

Each line contains the ISO country code, the ISO language code, and the name of the country in that language.

For example, here's Luxembourg (country code LU) in around 75 languages, after loading that file into a spreadsheet:

```
LU  af  Luxemburg
LU  am  ሉክሰምበርግ
LU  ar  لوكسمبورج
LU  az  Lüksemburq
LU  be  Люксембург
LU  bg  Люксембург
LU  bn  লাক্সেমবার্গ
LU  bo  ལཀ་ཛམ་བོརྒ།
LU  ca  Luxemburg
LU  cs  Lucembursko
LU  cy  Lwcsembwrg
LU  da  Luxembourg
LU  de  Luxemburg
LU  el  Λουξεμβούργο
LU  en  Luxembourg
LU  eo  Luksemburgo
LU  es  Luxemburgo
LU  et  Luksemburg
LU  eu  Luxenburgo
LU  fa  لوکزامبورگ
LU  fi  Luxemburg
LU  fo  Luksemborg
LU  fr  Luxembourg
LU  fur Lussemburc
LU  ga  Lucsamburg
LU  gl  Luxemburgo
LU  gsw Luxemburg
LU  gu  લક્ઝમબર્ગ
LU  he  לוקסמבורג
LU  hi  लक्समबर्ग
LU  hr  Luksemburg
LU  hu  Luxemburg
LU  hy  Լյուքսեմբուրգ
LU  id  Luxembourg
LU  is  Lúxemborg
LU  it  Lussemburgo
LU  ja  ルクセンブルグ
LU  ka  ლუქსემბურგი
LU  km  លុចហ្សំបួរ
LU  kn  ಲಕ್ಸಂಬರ್ಗ್
LU  ko  룩셈부르크
LU  ln  Luksamburg
LU  lo  ລຸກແຊມເບີກ
LU  lt  Liuksemburgas
LU  lv  Luksemburga
LU  mk  Луксембург
LU  ml  ലക്സംബര്‍ഗ്
LU  mr  लक्झेंबर्ग
LU  ms  Luksembourg
LU  mt  Lussemburgu
LU  my  လူဇင်ဘတ်
LU  nb  Luxembourg
LU  nds Luxemborg
LU  ne  लक्जेमबर्ग
LU  nl  Luxemburg
LU  nn  Luxembourg
LU  or  ଲକ୍ସେମବର୍ଗ
LU  pl  Luksemburg
LU  pt  Luxemburgo
LU  ro  Luxemburg
LU  ru  Люксембург
LU  se  Luxembourg
LU  sk  Luxembursko
LU  sl  Luksemburg
LU  so  Luksemboorg
LU  sq  Luksemburg
LU  sr  Луксембург
LU  sv  Luxemburg
LU  sw  Luksemburg
LU  ta  லக்ஸ்சம்பர்க்
LU  te  లక్సంబర్గ్
LU  th  ลักเซมเบิร์ก
LU  tr  Lüksemburg
LU  uk  Люксембург
LU  vi  Lúc-xăm-bua
LU  zh  卢森堡
```

Scroll down the above list to see all the languages.

A more authoritative source, but in a less convenient form, would be the Unicode CLDR files you mention. In the file for [Portuguese](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/summary/pt.html) (for example) country names are listed as "names / territory" starting at about line 2340.

Comment: Thank you Rob! That's exactly it, easy to do a cross-tab if I want a table as I showed it but that normalised format may well be better.

Comment: It seems like the link is broken :(

Answer (score 4):

There is a popular GitHub repo that has CSV, XML and JSON country lists in several languages.

[LINK](https://github.com/mledoze/countries)

Unfortunately, the translations are only:

```
"translations": {
    "de": "Österreich",
    "es": "Austria",
    "fr": "Autriche",
    "it": "Austria",
    "ja": "オーストリア",
    "nl": "Oostenrijk",
    "hr": "Austrija"
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to scrape the country name from Wikipedia. Not so useful after @Anastasios Ventouris's answer, but I'll post it anyway.

Each wiki page has a link to different language pages

[image: germany wikipedia language options]

HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-ace"><a href="//ace.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeureuman" title="Jeureuman – Achinese" lang="ace" hreflang="ace">Acèh</a></li>
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-kbd"><a href="//kbd.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8D%D0%BD" title="Джэрмэн – Kabardian" lang="kbd" hreflang="kbd">Адыгэбзэ</a></li>
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-af"><a href="//af.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duitsland" title="Duitsland – Afrikaans" lang="af" hreflang="af">Afrikaans</a></li>
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-am"><a href="//am.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%8C%80%E1%88%AD%E1%88%98%E1%8A%95" title="ጀርመን – Amharic" lang="am" hreflang="am">አማርኛ</a></li>
....
```

Easy to scrape (python 2.7 here). Just need to expand countries list. There is more data, this is just the country name in all available wiki languages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
countries = []
countries.append('Germany')
urlbase = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'

for country in countries:
    r = requests.get(url=urlbase+country)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
names = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'interlanguage-link'})  
for item in names:
    print country, item.encode('utf-8')
```

gives ugly but useful output of:

```
Germany <li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-ace"><a href="//ace.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeureuman" hreflang="ace" lang="ace" title="Jeureuman – Achinese">Acèh</a></li>
Germany <li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-kbd"><a href="//kbd.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8D%D0%BD" hreflang="kbd" lang="kbd" title="Джэрмэн – Kabardian">Адыгэбзэ</a></li>
Germany <li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-af"><a href="//af.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duitsland" hreflang="af" lang="af" title="Duitsland – Afrikaans">Afrikaans</a></li>
```

Comment: See also this question to transform wikipedia table into machine readable format: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/823/wikipedia-table-to-json-or-other-machine-readable-format

Comment: Thanks philshem, I was hoping to avoid scraping and having to learn Python, but I can see the general techniques of Wikipedia-to-machine-readable would be useful for other applications.

Answer (score 3):

I set up a spreadsheet derived from [UN Multilingual Terminology Database](https://unterm.un.org/) for you [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10efeLNKHd0ORpIkhN0KMdK4ud6HmFPPYd3MxH_TUySA/edit#gid=1064901875)

Comment: Thanks, user2542. There are only six languages there, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a great list for what you are looking. Here is the [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_names_in_various_languages) and here is an example: [Countries A-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_names_in_various_languages_%28A%E2%80%93C%29).

If you are satistfied with the data, just let me know and I will create a CSV file for what you need and update the answer here with a new link.

Comment: Thanks Anastasios but that's the page I was referring to when I referred to readable but run together.

English Name Other name(s) or older name(s)
Afghanistan  Afeganistão (Portuguese), Afghanistan (Welsh), An Afganastáin (Irish), 
 
So that's too much work to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSV dataset I made of the official country names in English, French, Spanish, German and Italian from:

BGN : U.S. Board on Geographic Names
UNGEGN : United Nations Group of Experts on Geographic Names
PCGN : U.K. Permanent Committee on Geographic Names
FAO : United Nations Food & Agriculture Organization
FFO : German Federal Foreign Office

http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#countrynames

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer's link appears to be broken I share here the best I could find from a [github repository](https://github.com/stefangabos/world_countries) that is quite active. There are 193 country names translated in 30 languages:
*ar*, *bg*, *cs*, *da*, *de*, *el*, *en*, *eo*, *es*, *et*, *eu*, *fi*, *fr*, *hu*, *it*, *ja*, *ko*, *lt*, *nl*, *no*, *pl*, *pt*, *ro*, *ru*, *sk*, *sv*, *th*, *uk*, *zh*, *zh-tw*.

The file is accessible [here](https://github.com/stefangabos/world_countries/blob/master/data/countries/_combined/countries.csv).