# Is there a database that provides metadata for products with barcodes?

Tags: metadata, products

I am looking for a database (free or paid, but I prefer a free one for now), that contains metadata of products such as cell phones, tv's, etc.

Comment: Is it different from this question? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes

Answer (score 2):

I believe I recently had the same question here: [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/downloadable-smartphones-data-name-specs)

However I did not recieve a link to a good website (except recommendations to scrape info from wiki/DB pedia) after lots of searching I came across: [IceCat](http://icecat.biz/)
However, their free open data set consist only out of daily items. I tried to contact them to have them give me info about FullIcecat, but I haven't had any response yet.

Answer (score -1):

you could check out [Semantics3](https://www.semantics3.com/). It is paid but you can do a couple of lookups to test the data using the [UPC Lookup tool](https://www.semantics3.com/tools/upc-lookup).