# Find a home for (old) video datasets

Tags: data-request, download, video

While looking for some older sets like PETS2006, which seems to be no longer available, i wondered if there might be already a place for them to be shared forever.

If there is none, i would encourage everyone to think about a good, free and open solution.

I know there are some sites out there which collect links - unfortunately a big part of the links is dead.

Comment: not sure if any of the answers has hosting capabilities for such large datasets like video, but check out the resources https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1576/1511

Comment: another option is a torrent --> https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4080/1511