# Is there a free publicly-accessible repository to store datasets derived from experiments?

Tags: releasing-data

I had obtained some results based on sensor data obtained from experiments that I had conducted.

In the interest of allowing others to reproduce or improve on my work, is there a way to make this data available online in a way that is free and publicly-accessible?

Comment: there are lots of places to host (Github being the most common, and not requiring registration for a public dataset), but make sure to link to it!

Comment: @philshem Would it be possible for this duplicate to remain in existence? With the the wording I used to ask the question, I never would've found the other question asked on this SE (this one: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/768/lets-suppose-i-have-potentially-interesting-data-how-to-distribute).

Comment: sure, especially since it has 2 answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://www.nature.com/sdata/policies/repositories#general), it shows the following table of data repositories.

[image: Options for sharing data]

[Open Science Framework](https://osf.io/), [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/), and [Mendeley Data](https://data.mendeley.com/) are the most viable options for free data sharing. With the other options either not being completely free nor accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://www.kaggle.com may be a good place. I´ve never used it myself (to publish but i´ve used many datasets), but a lot of people in academy or data scientist refer to kaggle when looking for datasets.

Comment: I tried testing it and found that there was a disadvantage of requiring a sign-in to access any of the data, so its not as accessible as an alternative like Zenodo.

Comment: You are right !... I´m going to check Zenodo ;)